# Error says it's dividing by zero while it's not initialised as zero

Tags: java, bluej

Im trying to find if the number is automorphic, the code compiles fine but it says there is divide by zero on the line where i've marked it

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class AutoLoop
{
    public static void main()
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number to check if it's automorphic or not");
        int num = sc.nextInt();
        int sqr = num*num;
        int sqrSave=sqr;
        int divisor = 10;
        int counter = 1;
        while (counter<=100)
        {
            sqr = sqr%divisor;  //It says there is divide by zero error on this line
            if (sqr==num)
            {
                System.out.println("Number is an automorphic number");
                break;
            }
            sqr=sqrSave;
            divisor*=10;
            counter++;
            if (counter == 100)
                 System.out.println("Number is not an automorphic number till the 100th digit.");
        }
    }
}
```

i've already tried making it     sqr%=divisor;    still doesn't work.

Comment: You cannot fit a 100-digit number into an `int`. So it will overflow, and maybe become `0` that way.

Comment: what is the value of `num`?

Comment: num is a user input number. also it says divide by zero error when im using numbers as small as 2. it seems that whenever there is any number input other than an automorphic number, it gives the error.

Comment: Seems unrelated but i don't see your class as public. How are you really able to execute main method? Also main function doesnt have String[] args. Can you share complete example

Comment: im using bluej, it gives me the option to directly execute class. im still in 9th grade

Comment: I understand.... let me share sample

Comment: my teacher said that using string args[] is optional in programs, as it will run whether it is present or not, and my codes run without it, so i never saw any problem with it

Comment: It is as @Thilo says, note that the divsion by 0 doesn't happen directly. Add the following line right before the line that causes the error `System.out.printf("%d %d\\n", sqr, divisor);` for some clarification of the error

Comment: The problem is fixed! @Thilo was right, it becomes 0, but not because of fitting 100 digits in an integer. The problem is that it was declared as integer in the first place. I changed it to double and now the program is working. Thanks!

Comment: You keep multiplying by `10` on each iteration, at some point it becomes `0` due to [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) and thus causing the division by 0 arithmetic exception. Just add `System.out.println("divisor " + divisor);` add the top of your loop and you will see it with your own eyes.

Comment: Umm ... your version that uses `double` is only working in the sense that it is not throwing an exception.  As `divisor` gets larger it will lose accuracy in the lower digits.  Since the lower digits are critical in computing `sqr`, you are liable to end up with the wrong answer.

Comment: @www.hybriscx.com *main* class must not be `public` anymore, but missing `String[]` (or `String...`) argument is a problem (*normal* Java)

Comment: Thanks for info Carlos. It gives me a trigger to upgrade my knowledge :) I like constructive comments. Really appreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tested your code and it seems to be that you try to multiply the divisor variable past the 32 bit integer limit, and since that is not possible, it becomes some other numbers, and after a while it turns into a zero. This happens every time you enter an non-automorphic number

This is the value of the divisor every time your code loops around:

```
10

100

1000

10000

100000

1000000

10000000

100000000

1000000000

1410065408

1215752192

-727379968

1316134912

276447232

-1530494976

1874919424

1569325056

-1486618624

-1981284352

1661992960

-559939584

-1304428544

-159383552

-1593835520

1241513984

-469762048

-402653184

268435456

-1610612736

1073741824

-2147483648

0
```

A fix for this may be to make the divisor an double or float instead of an integer

Answer (score 1):

Initially the divisor is 10. Then the loop causes the divisor to be multiplied a hundred odd times by 10, giving 10<sup>101</sup>. This overflows the int range several times, as 2<sup>31</sup> is approximately 2*10<sup>30</sup>.

Especially 10<sup>1000</sup> = 2<sup>100</sup>*5<sup>100</sup>, so after looping 32 times, multiply every time by 2, all bits of the `divisor` are zero.

If by the overflow `divisor` becomes 0 you get such a divide by zero error. As modulo `%` implies abstractly a division internally (modulo is remainder by division).

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class AutoLoop{
    public static void main(){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number to check if it's     automorphic or not");
        int num = sc.nextInt();
        int sqr = num*num;
        int sqrSave=sqr;
        int divisor = 10;
        int counter = 1;
        /* try with 10 and see the result. 100 is too big*/
        while (counter<=100){
            sqr = sqr%divisor;
            if (sqr==num){
                System.out.println("Number is an automorphic number");
                break;
            }
            sqr=sqrSave;
            divisor*=10;
            counter++;
            // try with 10 or an other number smaller than 100
            if (counter == 100)System.out.println("Number is not an automorphic number till the 100th digit.");
    }
}
```